# Creating a .bmp grayscale image from a vector of uint8_t

Tags: c++, image, file-io

I'm trying read a `.bmp` grayscale image from a file with a given width and height, convert it to `std::vector<uint8_t>`, run some sort of filter function on that vector, and then create a new image from that `std::vector`. I'm stuck in the last part.

How do I create a .bmp file from a given `std::vector<uint8_t>`, height and width?

P.S. I'm trying to do this without using external libraries.

This is the code I have thus far:

```
class Image {
    int weight;
    int width;
    std::vector<uint8_t> image;
    Image(int weight,int width) : weight(weight),width(width);
    void read_image(char* pic);
    void save_image(const std::vector<uint8_t>& new_image);
    std::vector<uint8_t> filter_image(int ww,int wh,double filter);
};

void Image::read_image(char *pic) {
    std::ifstream file(pic,std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::binary);
    if(!file.is_open()) return;
    while(file.peek()!=EOF){
        this->image.push_back(static_cast<uint8_t>(file.get()));
    }
}

void Image::save_image(const std::vector<uint8_t> &new_image) {
    //what to do here?
}
```

Comment: Why are you avoiding external libraries? If you really don't want to use them, read the specifications regarding whichever file format you are interested in outputting, and then output data in that format.

Comment: JPEG is not a trivial format to write. Don't reinvent the wheel, use a library. https://github.com/nothings/stb/blob/master/stb_image_write.h

Comment: Looks like you are using the C++ libraries to me.

Comment: in another format it will work? .jpg maybe? ive edited with my code thus far for context..

Comment: Many JPEG libraries have functions for converting a 2D array into a JPEG format.  Review the functions in your library.

Comment: Im not locked on the JPEG format, it can be in another format the main issue here is not using an external black-box method...

Comment: @stark to be fair, using the standard libraries is a different beast to using external libraries. I suspect OP wants practice, though the first comment should solve that problem

Comment: OP is trying to practice :(

Comment: bmp or tga are good for learning, While you're at it, there are much more efficient ways to read a file into a vector.

Comment: great so lets say its a .bmp image..

Comment: The first comment is all you need.  You want to learn, so asking us for code isn't going to do that any more than using a library would. Read the spec, write the code.

Comment: @GeckoGeorge Life isn't fair.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A .bmp file does not only store raw pixel data. It begins with a header describing the image stored inside the file: width, height, pixel size, color type, etc... The `read_image()` function you wrote reads the whole file, including the header, and running any image processing algorithm on your vector will ruin your data and produce garbage.

If you are learning image processing, it would be far easier to use raw image files. A raw image file contains only pixel data, without any metadata. When working with a raw image file, it is your responsibility to know the width and height of the image, as well as the pixel encoding.

Converting an image file to a raw image file, and vice versa, involves the use of an external tool. [ffmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/) is such a tool. ffmpeg is a linux tool, but it should be easy to find ffmpeg packaged for any operating system.

For converting from a file in almost any format to a raw image file (ffmpeg deduces the size of the image from the input file). The order of each parameter is important:

```
ffmpeg -i your_file.jpeg -f rawvideo -c rawvideo -pix_fmt gray output.raw
```

When converting back to your input format, you have to explicitly tell ffmpeg the size of your picture. Again the order of each parameter is important:

```
ffmpeg -f rawvideo -c rawvideo -pix_fmt gray -s 1280x720 -i input.raw your_processed_file.jpeg
```

Adapt the width and height to the real size of your image, or ffmpeg will resize the image. you can also play with the pixel type: `gray` specifies an 8 bits per pixel grayscale format, but you can use `rgb24` to keep color information (use `ffmpeg -pix_fmts` to see a list of all available formats).

If you are lucky enough to have `ffplay` availabel in your ffmpeg package, you can view the raw file directly on screen:

```
ffplay -f rawvideo -c rawvideo -pix_fmt gray -s 1280x720 input.raw
```

Additionally some image processing software are able to open a raw image file: gimp, photoshop, ...